# check whether angular array object has a specified value or not

Tags: angular, arraylist, angular6

I have an list of following object:

```
class Student : {
    IndexNo : string;
    Subject : string;
    Name : string;
    isAvailable : boolean
}
students: Student[];
```

I want to check whether "isAvailable" is true or not for any of the students.

Comment: Please come up with little bit of code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if students is your array:

check if all array has a student with isAvailable true:

```
const found = students.some(item => item.isAvailable == true)
```

get the index of first student with isAvailable true (if there is not such an element, returns -1):

```
const index = students.findIndex(item => item.isAvailable === true)
```

get array of all elements with isAvailable true:

```
const availableStudents = students.filter(item => item.isAvailable === true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array.some

```
const found = yourArray.some(item => item.isAvailable == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is wrong. Anyway you need to create an array of students. Then loop through it to see if any student is Available. Array `Some` method will exit the loop if the provided condition matches.

```
private students: Array<{ IndexNo: string, Subject: string, Name: string, isAvailable: boolean }> = [];
const ifAnyTrue: boolean = this.students.some((student: { IndexNo: string, Subject: string, Name: string, isAvailable: boolean }) => student.isAvailable);
```